# Unity 2D: how to play 2 animations at once?

Tags: unity-game-engine

so recently I started working with Unity animator, pretty cool, but got an issue.
I want to play "walk" animation and whenever preson gets a gun play another "hold" animation.
I tried to make 2 layers with usual walking and beneath it gun holding animation, but it just overrides with gun holding animation.
Any ideas?
Edit: screenies
[image]
[image]

Comment: We more context on your issue; Share screenshots on how you set-up your animations and it's layers?

Comment: Did you mask the layers?

Comment: Here are the screenshots

Answer (score 0):

As KinyL states, you need to add an Avatar Mask to the upper body layer. In the Mask, uncheck the lower body elements and you'll be good to go.

Comment: I checked them, that's just what I wanted! But, I don't know how to make those masks work for my character, since it's something extraordinary.